# How to select variable with keywords in Unix shell script?

Tags: shell, variables, unix, count, keyword

I have a shell script name `count.sh`; inside this script I have multiple variables, like
**`$INPUT_1`, `$INPUT_2`, `$OUTPUT_1`, `$OUTPUT_2`**; each variable represents a file. I want to count the lines of each file with **wc -l** , I tried **wc -l $INPUT_1** and it worked, but what I want to do is to find a way to apply **wc -l**  on every variable whose name contains the keyword **INPUT** or **OUTPUT**, similar principle with **`ls *keyword*`**. I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: `ls` is not a keyword at all -- it's an external command; if it didn't exist in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` it would just be a "command not found" error.

Comment: BTW, instead of `INPUT_1` / `INPUT_2` / etc, have you considered using an array? `inputs=( [1]="something" [2]="something else" )`, then it's just `for input in "${inputs[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: It's messy, but you can use `set | sed -n '/^[_[:alpha:][[:alnum:]_]*=/s/=.*//p'` to get a list of all variables, exported and not exported, and you can then filter that to select the names you want (`grep -E -e 'INPUT|OUTPUT'`) and then you have variable names — and if you get `varname=INPUT_1`, you can use `${!varname}` to get the value of `$INPUT_1`.  It isn't a good way of doing things, though.

Comment: Actually the variable names are created by others, they may be $INPUT_AB, $OUTPUT_g, etc. The only certain thing is that the variables all contain keyword INPUT/OUTPUT. I want to write a shell script count.sh so when others execute count.sh in their scripts, all variables including the keyword INPUT or OUTPUT will selected and counted lines (each variable contain a specific file)